# Modern way to split TypeScript d.ts files

Tags: typescript

I've created type definitions for an NPM module.
Everything is in the `index.d.ts` file, but I'd like to split it in multiple, more understandable, pieces.

The current `index.d.ts` file is basically

```
declare module 'bpmn-js' {
  export default class BpmnJS {
    ...
  }

  export class EventBus {
    ...
  }

  export interface InternalEvent {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

I'd like, for example, to extract `EventBus` on its own `d.ts` file, and then include it in the `index`.
Everything I'm able to find still uses `/// <reference>` comments, but I don't think this is the recommended way anymore, right?